# Possible to recover columns deleted by dplyr::select?

Tags: r, dplyr

I was foolish and removed some columns from the same dataframe, instead of saving it as a different dataframe, e.g. `x <- x %>% select(a)`. If `x` originally contained `a` and `b`, is there any way to recover `b`?

Comment: Rerun the code that created `x` in the first place, and stop before `select(a)`. No other way to go back.

Comment: It took 6 hours because I was creating a bunch of document vectors. I'll probably just rerun it tonight.

Comment: When you have processes that take a long time, write out intermediate results periodically. `saveRDS()` or `save()` are good for writing R objects including all the class information.

Comment: Is there any way I can do that during a mutate that goes through every line? Or would I just need to use a standard looping procedure?

Comment: Writing to disk is relatively expensive. Your *probably* don't want to write to disk in the middle of operations---complete the whole operation, then write the result. Your code creating `x` completed before, so it should be able to complete again, and then you can write the results before doing more with them. If you have doubts about your code completing, then I'd suggest working in batches that run in a more reasonable time and write the results for each batch--and yes, a `for` loop would be the most straightforward way to implement---but of course batching is more work for you to manage.

Comment: I agree with GregorThomas completely. My technique when developing a computationally-difficult stretch of code is to run sequence (pipe) leading up to a pivot/reshape or reduction/summarization, which often includes dropping unneeded columns. I then start another pipe (into a new variable) that starts with dropping columns and the reshape/summary, and go again until I need to do some data-dropping step. This is my "dev" flow. The only times I deviate is when it is memory-large and I cannot afford lingering variables, but this is rare for me (even with object sizes over 800MB each).